# How do I force Visual Studio to make this project compatible with VS 2022?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2022

I installed VS 2022 Community and am trying to work on a project that was developed on VS 2008 Pro. VS is giving me this report:

[image]

How do I force VS to make whatever upgrades it needs in order to run this program? I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: I see the word "handheld" in there. Does the first project listed target the .NET Compact Framework? If so then you're out of luck. I think that VS 2008 was the last version that included Compact Framework support.

Comment: @jmcilhinney oof yea, that might be the case here. I have source code for the project, how do I check to see if it uses the .NET Compact framework?

Comment: I've never actually created a CF project myself but I would expect that it would be specified in the VBPROJ file.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ah yea good call - I see a line in there about CF: `<Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v1.0'" Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.v1.targets" />`. There is also a second, similar line for v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

MS in their wisdom, dropped support for the Setup & Deployment project, can't remember when exactly, then after a bit of an uproar re-instated it through the Visual Studio marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that extension is installed by default these days, so there may be more required than just the installation. It would be worth checking what extensions are already installed. It may be that the new projects don't use the same project file format.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I had to install it when migrating an old project to VS2022

Answer (score 0):

Since your project has a file .vddproj, it might be a Smart Device CAB project.
It is not supported by later versions of visual studio.
It is recommended that you open it with VS2008.

Comment: Apparently we specifically need VS 2008 **Pro**. Do you know where I could find a download for this? I can't find one

Comment: Currently the VS 2008 Pro edition is not available on the website.

If you are an MSDN subscriber, you could download it from Subscriber downloads center , here is the download link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=visual%20studio%202008&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0